# How to combine ChoicePrompt and TextPrompt in the same step

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am using Microsoft Bot Framework V4 in node.js. In a step of a Dialog we need to combine buttons using the ChoicePrompt object but also the TextPrompt. In case the user clicks the buttons the suggested actions will be triggered, and if the user writes plain text, we handle the action using LUIS and certain intents. The problem is combining both actions.

I have tried to avoid re-prompting when using the ChoicePrompt, but I couldn't manage. Also I look for other prompts that directly could combine buttons and text but it seems there's not any.

First I declare the objects I am using in the prompt:

```js
class ExampleDialog extends LogoutDialog {
  constructor(userState, logger) {
    super(EXAMPLE_DIALOG);

    this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(TEXT_PROMPT));
    this.addDialog(new ChoicePrompt(CHOICE_PROMPT));
```

Second, in the steps, I use the prompts declared before:

```js
async firstStep(step) {    
  const promptOptions = {
    prompt: 'Text to prompt',
    retryPrompt: 'Retry text prompt',
    choices: ChoiceFactory.toChoices(['option1', 'option2', 'option3'])
  };

  const promptAction = await step.prompt(A_PROMPT_ID, promptOptions);

  return promptAction;
}

async secondStep(step) {
  const thePreviousStepResult = step.result.values
}
```

Comment: To be clear, you want the prompt to accept any string but still provide the user with buttons. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly this.

Comment: Is `LogoutDialog` a component dialog?

Comment: Yes, LogoutDialog extends from ComponentDialog, is needed for the login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text prompts are the way to go when you want to accept any string. Remember that you can include any activity as the `prompt` property of your prompt options, and that activity can contain attachments, suggested actions, etc. You can see in the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/prompts/prompt.ts#L277) that a choice prompt just calls `Prompt.appendChoices` which uses `ChoiceFactory` to generate the buttons for its activities. You can do the same thing:

```js
const promptOptions = {
    prompt: ChoiceFactory.forChannel(step.context, ['option1', 'option2', 'option3'], 'Text to prompt')
    // You can also include a retry prompt if you like,
    // but there's no need to include the choices property in a text prompt
};

const promptAction = await step.prompt(TEXT_PROMPT, promptOptions);

return promptAction;
```

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

Comment: Thanks so much!! :)

Comment: @ErnestoAlarcónGallo - If this helps you, please remember to upvote and accept my answer

Comment: I wanted to vote but I am still too new, as soon as I can I will do it. Sorry for this...

Comment: @ErnestoAlarcónGallo - This is an answer on your own question. Even if you can't upvote it, you can still accept it by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: I am looking for something this. Trying to give choices, but at the same time accept answer from text as well.. I tried this, but it doesn't work. The dialog keeps re-rendering. I believe the recognized.succeeded is not getting true wit this